# Determine the limit of the sequence $\left(\frac{1+2^k+3^k+...+n^k}{n^{k+1}}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to determine $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\frac{1+2^k+3^k+...+n^k}{n^{k+1}}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)$$

To this end, consider that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\frac{1+2^k+3^k+...+n^k}{n^{k+1}}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{i}{n})^k-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{k+1}\right)$$

At this point, I thought about using the definite integral to try to come up with something, but the result does not convince me.

Any help please?

Comment: What makes you think the limit exists? And which $k$ are you considering? For positive integral $k$ you can use Faulhaber's formula to simplify the expression.

Comment: If you work with the sum of a growing sequence, you can use the Euler–Maclaurin formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) - you get the answer immediately $$\sum_{i=1}^n f(i)=\int_1^n f(x)dx+\frac{1}{2}(f(n)+f(1))+\frac{1}{12}(f'(n)-f'(1))+...$$
In you case $f(i)=i^k$, and
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^k=\int_1^nx^kdx+\frac{1}{2}n^k+O(n^{k-1})=\frac{1}{k+1}n^{k+1}+\frac{1}{2}n^k+O(n^{k-1})$$
The limit - follows

Comment: @Svyatoslav This should be the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$ n\left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^k}{n^{k+1}} - \frac{1}{k+1} \right) = n \left ( \frac{(k+1)\sum_{i=1}^n i^k - n^{k+1}}{(k+1)n^{k+1}} \right) = \frac{(k+1)\sum_{i=1}^n i^k - n^{k+1}}{(k+1)n^k}$$
Let $a_n = (k+1)\sum_{i=1}^n i^k - (k+1)n^{k+1}$ and $b_n = (k+1)n^k$. Since $b_n$ is increasing to $+\infty$, by Stolz Cesaro, we can look at $$ \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n} = \frac{1}{k+1}\frac{(k+1)(n+1)^{k}-(n+1)^{k+1} + n^{k+1}}{(n+1)^{k}-n^k} $$
Now, by binomial formula, the denominator is of order $kn^{k-1} + o(n^{k-1})$ and the numerator is of order $(k+1)k(n+1)^{k-1} - {k+1 \choose 2}(n+1)^{k-1} + o(n^{k-1}) = {k+1 \choose 2}(n+1)^{k-1} + o(n^{k-1})$, hence $$ \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n} = \frac{{k+1 \choose 2}\left((n+1)^{k-1} + o(n^{k-1})\right)}{k(k+1)\left(n^{k-1} + o(n^{k-1})\right)} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} {k+1 \choose 2} \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \frac{1}{2}$$

and by Stolz-Cesaro $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to \frac{1}{2}$.